# Change invoice status in DB

Tags: invoice, magento2.2, authorize.net

We are getting problems with Authorize.net 'timing out' but then creating the order in Magento and then creating the transaction on Authorize.net.

To resolve, I have to go to Authorize.net and capture funds there. However, this leaves the invoice in Magento as unpaid.

Is there a place in the DB where I can change this status or is there some code to make the Authorize.net/Magento 2.2 connection more reliable? It doesn't happen often, but it happens enough to be annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In DB you can change 'state' Column value to 2 in 'sales_invoice' table.**

**Gel all invoice state :**  vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php

```
const STATE_OPEN = 1;

const STATE_PAID = 2;

const STATE_CANCELED = 3;
```

For changing the state by coding, looks this model : vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/InvoiceOrder.php

```
  $connection->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $order = $this->paymentAdapter->pay($order, $invoice, $capture);
            $order->setState(
                $this->orderStateResolver->getStateForOrder($order, [OrderStateResolverInterface::IN_PROGRESS])
            );
            $order->setStatus($this->config->getStateDefaultStatus($order->getState()));
            $invoice->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::STATE_PAID);
            $this->invoiceRepository->save($invoice);
            $this->orderRepository->save($order);
            $connection->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $connection->rollBack();
            throw new \Magento\Sales\Exception\CouldNotInvoiceException(
                __('Could not save an invoice, see error log for details')
            );
        }
```

Comment: I edited the DB via phpMyAdmin, and reindexed, but the orders I changed are still 'Pending' in Sales > Invoices

I'll keep digging, but this gets me closer for sure!

Comment: You have to update state column in 'sales_invoice_grid' table also.

Comment: That was it! "sales_invoice_table" and "sales_invoice_grid" - all invoices are correctly marked - thank you thank you!