# Order Status Processing after Shipment and Generate Invoice also Invoice status showing pending in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, sales-order, magento2.3, create-invoice

Shipment completed and generate invoice but order status showing Processing  and invoice is in pending.

> Also invoice showing a **Capture** button.

why? Anyone Know?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to select capture option during invoice creation

if you select

`Capture Offline` When the invoice is submitted, the system does not capture the payment. It is assumed that the payment is captured directly through the gateway, and you no longer have the option to capture this payment through Magento. `Invoice status goes to Paid`

`Capture online` When the invoice is submitted, the system captures the payment from the third-party payment gateway like when you charge credit cards using any gateway. `Invoice status goes to Pending`.

`Not Capture` When the invoice is submitted, the system does not capture the payment. It is assumed that you will capture the payment through Magento at a later date. There is a Capture button in the completed invoice. Before capturing, you are able to cancel the invoice.

For Reference: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/invoice-create.html

**I hope this will help**

Comment: So how to do invoice status pending to paid?

Comment: @JugalKishor you asked in the question why the invoice is in pending so I tell you the reason (It is because of capture option). In order to convert invoice status pending to paid you have to follow this thread ` https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205382/change-invoice-status-in-db `. As it has already been asked by some one so I don't want to mention it here to make it redundant. I hope you got my point. keep coding :) thanks :)

Comment: Yes I solved. Go In  database and search invoice and sales order tables  put processing to complete in stat column. solved

Comment: @Jugal if my answer is helpful please mark my answer correct so it helps other readers as well. keep coding :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

In DB change 'state' Column value to "2" in 'sales_invoice_grid' table.
and
In DB change 'state' Column value to "2" in 'sales_invoice' table.
and
In DB change 'state' and 'status' Column value to "complete" in 'sales_order' table.